# DRY code for Social icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

Im trying to implement Social links to my rails app but im starting to realized its going to be a bit repetitive. I want the appropriate icon to appear if a link is provided by user.

Here is what I have so far .

```
<% unless @user.github == nil %>
  <%= link_to @user.github , class: 'btn btn-social-social btn-github' do %>
   <span class="fa fa-github"></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here the Github icon will show up only if `github` its not nil . How can i do this to multiple links and at the same time keeping my Code DRY ?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a helper for that:

```
def social_icon_helper(user, service)
  if user.respond_to?(service) && !user.send(service).nil?
    link_to user.send(service), class: "btn btn-social-social btn-#{service}" do
      content_tag(:span, class: "fa fa-#{service}")
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<p>
  <%= social_icon_helper(@user, :github) %>
</p>
```

or even

```
<% %i(github facebook twitter).each do |service| %>
  <%= social_icon_helper(@user, service) %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, please find updated helper code. Please note that I added a `" #{service}"` after tag definition.

```
def social_icon_helper(user, service)
  if user.respond_to?(service) && !user.send(service).nil?
    link_to user.send(service), class: "btn btn-social-social btn-#{service}" do
      content_tag(:span, " #{service}", class: "fa fa-#{service}")
    end
  end
end
```

That helper produces the following link for me:

[image: github link]

Comment: Thank you im having one issue though . the helper ends up displaying `<span>{:class=&gt;&quot;fa fa-github&quot;}</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You'll only have a few of them, right? ~5 or so? In this case, I wouldn't bother too much about keeping the code DRY. The code for different links is different enough to make it not worth the effort (different object properties, css classes, etc.)

You have shown only one case (github), but I can easily imagine that for some cases the property and the css class will not match (for example, `user.google_plus` and `fa-gplus`, or something)

Just repeat the code 5 times and hide it in a partial.

If you insist, then @retgoat's answer should do.